# Fake extension method using exact arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock

I am writing tests for our C# 7 application and struggle with mocking an Extension method. I am using TypeMock 8.6.10.3.

Here is a simplified example:

```
internal class InnerClass
{
  private readonly string _description;

  public InnerClass(string description)
  {
    _description = description;
  }

  public string GetDescription()
  {
    return _description;
  }
}

internal class OuterClass
{  
  public void DoSthWithExtension(int someNumber)
  {
    var innerClass = new InnerClass("InnerClassDescription");
    innerClass.Extension(someNumber);
  }
}

internal static class Extensions
{
  public static void Extension(this InnerClass innerClass, int someNumber)
  {
    var d = innerClass.GetDescription();
  }
}

 public void TestExtension()
{
  // I want to fake the method "InnerClass.Extension()"
  // which is called by "OuterClass.DoSthWithExtension()".
  // I don't have access to the InnerClass instance though.
  // So unfortunately I have to fake them all.
  var fakedInnerClasses = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<InnerClass>();

  Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Extensions.Extension(fakedInnerClasses, 11)).WithExactArguments().DoInstead(
    c =>
    {
      // The test doesn't go in here. The second parameter is correct,
      // the first one obviously not. But what is expected as a first parameter then?

      var oc2 = new OuterClass();

      // Here I call InnerClass.Extension() again.
      // The test should now go into the faked method underneath.
      oc2.DoSthWithExtension(22);
    });

  Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Extensions.Extension(fakedInnerClasses, 22)).WithExactArguments().DoInstead(
    c =>
    {
      // As above, the test code doesn't go in here.
    });

  // In here an instance of InnerClass is created and
  // InnerClass.Extension(11) is called.
  var oc1 = new OuterClass();
  oc1.DoSthWithExtension(11);
}
```

As the `this` parameter of the Extension method I choose the faked instances of InnerClass. Thats what I assume is needed. But TypeMock does not bring me into the faked method. Obviously its the wrong parameter. But which one should I choose then?

Comment: Do not fake the extension method in this case. You know what the extension method calls. so fake that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. In my case this would be InnerClass.GetDescription(). But how can I fake it? The method is not static and I don't have the instance of InnerClass.

Comment: @telandor Create an interface that contains `GetDescription()` and make a fake class that implements that interface.

Comment: @telandor I deleted my answer based on your comment about the oversimplification of the current state of the question. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the *actual* problem. The deleted answer would have been based on the provided information.

Comment: To paraphrase from an article I read *While Typemock Isolator enables you to test poorly designed code, that’s not a green light to stop proper software design. You still need to design your application with good principles.*

Comment: I updated my code accordingly.

Comment: That part that is confusing is why the other outer class is needed. The shown inner class has no dependency on the outer, why would the mock then need to create a new outer class?

Comment: That aside, based on the [docs](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Ffakingallstaticmethodsofatype.htm) its appears that you need to setup the extension class so that you can fake the static calls.

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you for your idea. I will look at it.

Comment: The pointed exact Arguments in whenCalled are of type 'fakedInnerClasses' but you access the extension method via real instance of OuterClass. You need to create a fake of inner class(no need to fake all instances) and test the extension method with him.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments and updated question, the part that is confusing is why the other outer class is needed. The shown inner class has no dependency on the outer. Why would the mock then need to create a new outer class?

That aside, based on the [docs](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Ffakingallstaticmethodsofatype.htm) its appears that you need to setup the extension class so that you can fake the static extension calls.

```
Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(Extensions));

//...
```

---

#### Original answer

Do not fake the extension method in this case. You know what the extension method calls. so fake that.

```
public void TestExtension() {
    //Arrange
    string expected = "Fake result";
    var fakedInnerClasses = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<InnerClass>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakedInnerClasses.GetDescription())
        .WillReturn(expected);

    var subject = new OuterClass();

    //Act
    subject.DoSthWithExtension();
    
    
    //Assert
    //...
}
```

So now when the outer is called and the extension method invoked, it will be acting on the mock controlled by you.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I guess my simplified example is too simplified. Within the faked method I want to create a second instance of OuterClass which as well calls DoSthWithExtension(). Indirectly InnerClass.Extension() is called again and this call should end up in a faked method again. So far I haven't found out how to accomplish this. To differentiate these two calls I want to rely on the two parameters of Extension() (in the real application there are two parameters, not just 'this'). One of them is 'this' which I don't know how to fake. I will edit my question. Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: Thank you. But Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods() does not help unfortunately.